# Apple Watch Complication - Open App at click

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, apple-watch-complication, watchos-5

I want to create a complication for my WatchOS App, therefore I activated the option for the complication in XCode and set up some images for all complication types.

Now I can see my complication on my Apple Watch 4, but if I click on the complication, the last visited site of my WatchOS App is shown and frozen. I can't interact with any elements. Its like the Screen shows only a Snapshot of my App.

I don't know if this is connected to this question, but running the complication throws me following error:

> WatchKit Extension[42453:6631490] [default] -[SPApplicationDelegate application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:]:1178: Couldn't find the SPInterfaceViewController. Bailing

Is there a way to fix this bug, so that i can click on my complication and my WatchOS App is running like opening it from the menu?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you entered a radar... um, (whatever they call it now) on this?

Comment: Can you also add to your post your environment. (iOS, watchOS, Xcode versions)

Comment: Same issue when tap any button action of notification received on watch, sometime it says [SPInterfaceImageView release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x24d19480